# Search multiple Elements with XPATH having unknown namespace prefix EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xpath, element

I am loading different XML files that contain different `xmlns namespaces having specific prefixes` e.g. `x,i,s,dt,xx etc.` that change with different XML files. I am searching for multiple Element nodes e.g., `AttributeType` that may be prefixed with the namespace prefix.

My question is, how do i select the multiple nodes `using VBA` without knowing the xmlns Namespace prefix (e.g. whether it will be `s` or `xx`) that may be prefixed to the node?

Example:

```
<xml 
xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
    <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:updatable="true">
            <s:AttributeType name="F1" rs:number="1" rs:nullable="true" rs:maydefer="true" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basetable="abc$" rs:basecolumn="F1">
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="F2" rs:number="1" rs:nullable="true" rs:maydefer="true" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basetable="abc$" rs:basecolumn="F2">
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
....
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row F2="F2" F4="F4" F5="F5"/>
    <z:row F1="1.3" F2="2.3" F5="1.1"/>
    <z:row F1="3.4" F3="2.8" F4="5.3"/>
....
</xml>
```

Another example:

```
<xml 
xmlns:xx="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
    <xx:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
        <xx:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:updatable="true">
            <xx:AttributeType name="F1" rs:number="1" rs:nullable="true" rs:maydefer="true" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basetable="abc$" rs:basecolumn="F1">
                <xx:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </xx:AttributeType>
            <xx:AttributeType name="F2" rs:number="1" rs:nullable="true" rs:maydefer="true" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basetable="abc$" rs:basecolumn="F2">
                <xx:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </xx:AttributeType>
....
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row F2="F2" F4="F4" F5="F5"/>
    <z:row F1="1.3" F2="2.3" F5="1.1"/>
    <z:row F1="3.4" F3="2.8" F4="5.3"/>
....
</xml>
```

Here is a sample VBA code:

```
Sub TestMe()

Dim XML As Object
Dim sFilePath As String, sXML As String, K As Variant, FirstDataRow As Object
Dim oRS As Object, Attr_XPath As String, FirstDataRow_XPath As String
Dim Attrs As Object, Attr As Object, I As Long, J As Long

sFilePath = "C:\Test_ADO.xml"
Set XML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XML.Load (sFilePath)

Attr_XPath = "//@*[name()='AttributeType']"
FirstDataRow_XPath = "//@*[name()='row']"

Set Attrs = XML.SelectNodes(Attr_XPath)
Set FirstDataRow = XML.SelectSingleNode(FirstDataRow_XPath)

Stop
For Each K In FirstDataRow.Attributes
    For Each Attr In Attrs
   '....
    Next Attr
Next K

....
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The namespace agnostic way to build XPath expression is simple but makes expressions much longer. For each element you supply following subexpression:

```
/*[local-name()='AttributeType']
```

name() function returns prefix and local name of the element, e.g. "s:AttributeType" and local-name() returns only the local part of it.

Comment: I tried implementing this in above vba code, but doesn't work!

Comment: Did you tried complete XPath expression /*[local-name()='xml']/*[local-name()='Schema']/*[local-name()='ElementType']/*[local-name()='AttributeType'] or reduced one //*[local-name()='AttributeType'] ?